# Use ajax to filter column 1 of CSV and display column 2 data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'd like to have a simple HTML dropdown select list, that when an option is selected, it acts as a filter for the first column of a CSV, then the filtered data from the second column is displayed.

Here is a codepen I'm working on: http://codepen.io/oreoloveboss/pen/ZePpPd?editors=1010
I am able to load the CSV and display it with the following code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B9qMSGDUnssqd1hFTVUxak0wRHc",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
       $.each(data.split(/[\n\r]+/), function(index, line) {
        $('<li>').text(line).appendTo('#client-data');
       });
    },
     async: true
    });
```

});

But I am little lost on how to both filter it, and use variables from the html select list as the filters. In that codepen the CSV is 2 columns, one is letters A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B and the second is numbers 1,2,3,4,5,100,101,102,103,104,105.

Comment: So split it on the comma, compare first value to the select. If matches, append it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there!  You just didn't have a way of specifying the column:

```
$('<li>').text(line.split(/\t/)[1]).appendTo('#client-data'); //grab the second element
```

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B9qMSGDUnssqd1hFTVUxak0wRHc",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
       $.each(data.split(/[\n\r]+/), function(index, line) {
        temp = line.split(/\t/);
        if (temp[0] == "A")
         $('<li>').text(temp[1]).appendTo('#client-data');
       });
    },
     async: true
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="client-data">

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to check if the value from the first column matches a variable and then outputting the second element?

Not luck with this, I'm probably going about it the wrong way:

 `if (  $.line.split(/\t/)[0] == var) {`

Comment: Updated the code inside the post.  If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much! Working perfectly, just had to set the function to run when the select changes, and clear it `.html("")` before appending everything